# Intermittent Start-up. (I've hit a wall) 2000 Ford Explorer

Tags: ford, starting, explorer

About 2-3 months ago my car wouldn't start. I would turn the key and nothing would happen. It was completely dead and I had no idea what to do. Being an inexperienced car person the first thing I did was change my starter. Obviously, that didn't do anything because my car wasn't getting any power. I then noticed that my battery terminals were being eaten by corrosion. So, I cleaned my wires and got completely new terminals. My car ran fine for about two weeks. Then it wouldn't start again. This time it was clearly my alternator. I replaced it and while I was at it replaced my battery. It ran for about a week. then once again it wouldn't  start. This time I'd turn my key and the only thing that would happen is the lights on my dash would turn on. I talked to a friend who is a bit more car savvy and he suggested that perhaps my starter was bad. So, I thought what the heck? I'll just change it again and see what happens. So, I took my brand new starter out... it had only been in my car two weeks. I took it to the store and had it tested. Sure enough it was broken. I got a new starter and two weeks later my car doesn't start... My timeline is a little faulty. However, I've replaced my battery, my alternator, both terminals, and my starter twice. I am skeptical that it is my starter this time just because I don't want to have to replace it a third time. Also it started up with a jumpstart... Surely my starter isn't broken again?

I drive a 2000 Ford Explorer and all of this started happening after 200,000 miles. I am now at 201,000 miles. All of this has happened within 1,000 miles. I'm getting pretty desperate any and all help is appreciated.

Comment: I'd probably start by checking your battery, use a decent multimeter with a min max function. Then do some circuit testing. Voltage drop the battery posts to terminals and the terminals to their respective points.

Comment: Check your engine ground. If it's corroded or frayed, you won't get enough juice out of the battery for the starter to operate.